# AvalonDock dock a window

Tags: c#, wpf, window, dock, avalondock

I am trying to convert my app in WPF to work with `AvalonDock`. I have a few windows(about 10) and main form that has `DockingManager`. I would like to put those windows inside that `DockingManager`.
I've tried this:

```
<ad:DockingManager x:Name="MainWindow">
    <ad:DocumentPane x:Name="Windows" />
</ad:DockingManager>

FormDocumentSearch formDocumentSearch = new FormDocumentSearch(dc, this); //create window
DockableContent dct = new DockableContent() { Title = "Window" }; //create DockableContent
dct.Content = formDocumentSearch; //put the window in the DockableContent
Windows.Items.Add(dct);
```

This gives me the following error: `Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.`.

What can I do? How can I put a `Window` or how to modify them so that I can still use the designer and have them in `AvalonDock`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can add a window in side another window. Try to change window as Page.

change

```
<Window ... >

...

</Window>
```

to

```
<Page ... >

...

</Page>
```

For all windows you wanted to add as child.