# How to insert window as content of dockablepane

Tags: powerbuilder, avalondock

I got 1 main window that content 2 documentpane and 2 dockablepane.

Beside that I also have another 1 main window  that i plan to placing in one of dockablepane.

how to I do that?, I'm using `AvalonDock 1.3` and `PowerBuilder 12.5`.

before I have tried to use this method:

```
dockablepane.content=newWindow.innerControl

ERROR: null object reference
```

Comment: Can we assume this is PowerBuilder.NET, as opposed to PowerBuilder Classic? I hope this is obviously PB.NET, but it makes a world of difference.

Answer (score 0):

In [Bruce Armstrong's PowerBuilder Developer Journal article](http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/1947041), he loaded his panels with custom visual user objects. I guess I'd be surprised if you could load a *window* into a pane, given how much extra is implied in a window class. You could probably pretty easily convert a window (maybe with the exception of window-specific events) into a custom visual user object by copying and pasting carefully selected source.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Thanks a lot Terry, Im still beginner, I though there is the way to place window in dock in which I maybe don't know. I have tried these (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826634/how-to-place-instance-of-window-in-layoutanchorable-avalondock-2 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772768/avalondock-dock-a-window ) before, but I still cant do it. Thanks again for your respond :)

Comment: The "beginner" comment makes me more concerned to ask again what I asked above: are we talking PB Classic or PB.NET? The answers for each are completely different.

Comment: Yes, going third party to find a docking solution is going to be very different between WPF and Win32 (PB or otherwise). OK, so Avalon isn't completely off-track with WPF, but I'd suggest you need to follow the examples in the article I pointed out. A *window* isn't dockable, but a custom visual user object is. As far as you're concerned they're both just collections of controls / subclasses, but as far as the system goes, the CVUO doesn't have the wiring that's going to make it try to live independently.

Comment: So mean that, for my situation it's impossible for me to place main window in dockable pane/ pop up main window in  dock???

Comment: Convert it to a custom visual user object; you'll be fine.