# How to host WPF application in Winform using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

I have a simple WPF application MyWPF.exe,

```
namespace MyWPF
{
     /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
     /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {           

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     MessageBox.Show("Button is clicked");
    }
  }
}
```

I want to load this "MainWindow" in my Winform application, I tried like below, I am getting exception when creating instance as **"System.InvalidOperationException: Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual."**

```
        String path = @"D:\Test\MyForm\MyWPF\bin\Debug\MyWPF.exe";
        System.Reflection.Assembly myExeApp = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(path);
        System.Type MyWPFType = myExeApp.GetType("MyWPF.MainWindow");

        var MyWPFInstance = (System.Windows.Window)myExeApp.CreateInstance("MyWPF.MainWindow");

        ctrlHost = new ElementHost();
        ctrlHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(MyWPFInstance );
        ctrlHost.Child = MyWPFInstance ;
        this.Controls.Add(ctrlHost);
```

Is it possible or am I missing something? The entire exception is as below,

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.
   at System.Windows.Window.OnAncestorChanged()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorChangedInternal(TreeChangeInfo parentTreeState)
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnAncestorChanged(DependencyObject d, TreeChangeInfo info)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
   at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnTreeChange(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyObject parent, Boolean isAddOperation)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject newParent)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)
   at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.AddInternal(UIElement element)
   at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.Add(UIElement element)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.set_Child(UIElement value)
   at MyForm.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Test\MyForm\MyForm\Form1.cs:line 37
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: It sounds like you can't put a window inside of a control. Seems pretty reasonable. Instead of adding a *window* to your control host, why not use some other kind of container? A grid or some other panel maybe?

Comment: But I am able to do this with Winform inside in a Winform.

Comment: I certainly don't doubt that, but if you were going to completely redesign an API (like WPF), you might consider constraining things that don't technically make sense (like putting windows inside of windows). Besides, if it doesn't allow you to use a Window, you can just change your window to derive from `UserControl` (instead of `Window`), and problem solved.

Comment: But we are trying to embed third party WPF application in our Winform Application.

Comment: Right, and notice that the exception says "*Window* must be root of tree, not *Form* must be root of tree," which means the exception is being generated from WPF, not from Winforms. This is a WPF constraint. Someone else ran into the same problem: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772768/avalondock-dock-a-window).

Comment: As a conclusion, I can't do this.

Comment: You can, just don't use a `Window` as a container. There are plenty of other things you can use. You could even just change the base class of your current window from `Window` to `UserControl`, and that would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

`ElementHost` is not meant for this kind of interop. You can use any non-`Window` control as its child. You can refactor your WPF app so the main window contains **only** a user control, which you'll load using the reflection code and add to the form.

Alternatively, you can use Win32 `SetParent` to place the WPF window as a child of a Windows Forms control, but I definitely would avoid that.

Comment: I just want to try, and how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I know, that it is an old question, but maybe someone else is also searching for the solution.

Just put the line:
`ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(this);`
before `InitializeComponent();` in each of your WPF windows.

It helped me.